# How to turn character date into integer JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, integer

I need a way to turn my 2 character string dates (i.e. '04/10/2010' & '05/24/2010') into an integers to see if one is greater than the other. If the user enters an end date that is less than the begin date I need to popup an "invalid date range" error.

Comment: @DouweM In my opinion ( Java.syntax LIKE JavaScript.syntax ) === TRUE

Comment: @Jacob 
Java.libraries != JavaScript.libraries; Java.libraries.contains(jquery) == false;

Comment: @DouweM - very true, sorry--mistype

Comment: @Jacob That doesn't make it right to use the term "Java" in a question that's really about JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you posted your real problem is:

> I need to see if one date is greater than another in javascript/jquery.

If so all you need to use is the [Javascript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) (how to page [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp)).

You can use it as follows:

```
var dateTextA = '04/10/2010';
var dateTextB = '05/24/2010';
var dateA = new Date(dateTextA);
var dateB = new Date(dateTextB);
if (dateA < dateB){
    alert("Your date is out of range!");
}
```

*Note: Above code has been tested and works in IE7.*

If you really feel you need an integer value, you can use the [`UTC` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp) to get that.

Comment: @C. Ross - It looks like all the UTC functions on that page are converting a date to a string..I want to convert a string to date

Comment: @C. Ross - new Date(dateA) works perfectly, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `Date.parse('04/10/2010')` returns a timestamp (integer) for *April 10* in the US and *4 October* most other places.

It is best to use a less ambiguous format - if you are taking user input, give the user a calendar, menu, or three label inputs, then build the date from that.

3 inputs:

```
new Date(+fullyearinput, monthinput-1, +dateinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

If [Date won](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp)'t [parse](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp) what you are looking for, [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) provides a lot of syntactic sugar to make your life easier.

To compare two dates, all you need to do is turn your strings into Date objects and then use the greater than, less than, or equality operators.  Javascript provides Date comparison natively.